# Postgres Query Plan why Row estimation is so wrong

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, explain

**Postgres Version** : 12

**Query:**
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE TRUE, VERBOSE TRUE, COSTS TRUE, BUFFERS TRUE, TIMING TRUE)
SELECT MIN("id"), MAX("id") FROM "public"."hotel_slot_inventory" WHERE ( "updated_at" >= '2021-03-02 13:30:03' AND "updated_at" < '2021-03-03 06:15:19.127884' );

**Query Plan:**

```
 Result  (cost=512.44..512.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=57839.244..57839.250 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: $0, $1
   Buffers: shared hit=1 read=454374 written=185
   I/O Timings: read=54564.571 write=2.686
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..256.22 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=57599.761..57599.764 rows=1 loops=1)
           Output: hotel_slot_inventory.id
           Buffers: shared read=453546 written=185
           I/O Timings: read=54330.640 write=2.686
           ->  Index Only Scan using hotel_slot_inventory_id_updated_at_idx on public.hotel_slot_inventory  (cost=0.57..3285663.29 rows=12852 width=4) (actual time=57599.758..57599.759 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Output: hotel_slot_inventory.id
                 Index Cond: ((hotel_slot_inventory.id IS NOT NULL) AND (hotel_slot_inventory.updated_at >= '2021-03-02 13:30:03'::timestamp without time zone) AND (hotel_slot_inventory.updated_at < '2021-03-03 06:15:19.127884'::timestamp without time zone))
                 Heap Fetches: 0
                 Buffers: shared read=453546 written=185
                 I/O Timings: read=54330.640 write=2.686
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..256.22 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=239.468..239.470 rows=1 loops=1)
           Output: hotel_slot_inventory_1.id
           Buffers: shared hit=1 read=828
           I/O Timings: read=233.931
           ->  Index Only Scan Backward using hotel_slot_inventory_id_updated_at_idx on public.hotel_slot_inventory hotel_slot_inventory_1  (cost=0.57..3285663.29 rows=12852 width=4) (actual time=239.465..239.465 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Output: hotel_slot_inventory_1.id
                 Index Cond: ((hotel_slot_inventory_1.id IS NOT NULL) AND (hotel_slot_inventory_1.updated_at >= '2021-03-02 13:30:03'::timestamp without time zone) AND (hotel_slot_inventory_1.updated_at < '2021-03-03 06:15:19.127884'::timestamp without time zone))
                 Heap Fetches: 0
                 Buffers: shared hit=1 read=828
                 I/O Timings: read=233.931
 Planning Time: 10.577 ms
 Execution Time: 57839.332 ms
(28 rows)
```

In both the InitPlan, rows=12852 while actual rows=1. why is that? Limit clause has been added separately after Index only scan.

**Edit Index Bloat Details:**

real_size: 3751411712 = 3.49 GB

extra_size: 470237184 = 448 MB

extra_ratio:12.53

fillfactor: 90

bloat_size: 107053056 = 102 MB

bloat_ratio:2.85

**Table Bloat Size:**
bloat_size: 475283456 = 453 MB

bloat_ratio: 5.088

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an index is bloated out of shape. Try

```
REINDEX INDEX hotel_slot_inventory_id_updated_at_idx;
```

or

```
VACUUM (FULL) hotel_slot_inventory;
```

Comment: It read 453546 index buffers to get one row. Something's not right.

Comment: @laurenz: Index is not bloated.. I edited question and put the detailed there

Comment: Where do you see that information? It does not look like `pgstatindex` output, which is the only reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal.  The expected row count of the "index only scan" line gives the count of rows which is expected to satisfy the index condition, *if scanned to completion*.  The actual rows reflects the fact that the LIMIT made it stop early. Notice the cost estimate of the LIMIT is lower than the cost estimate of the index scan, because that estimate is also given for a complete scan, which is then be "backed off" by the LIMIT.

Comment: Since Limit made it stop early.... still why it scanned shared read=453546 buffers, it should have stopped at first matched index entry.

Comment: It did stop after first matched entry.  There were just a whole lot of mismatched entries first.