# Why Postgres is taking so much time in index only scan

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, explain

**Postgres Version**:12

**Query**:

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE TRUE, VERBOSE TRUE, COSTS TRUE, BUFFERS TRUE, TIMING TRUE)
SELECT MIN("id"), MAX("id") FROM "public"."hotel_slot_inventory" WHERE ( "updated_at" >= '2021-03-02 13:30:03' AND "updated_at" < '2021-03-03 06:15:19.127884' );

**Query Plan:**

```
 Result  (cost=512.17..512.18 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=65556.920..65556.926 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: $0, $1
   Buffers: shared hit=370 read=454012 written=8
   I/O Timings: read=62266.717 write=0.194
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..256.09 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=65251.998..65252.001 rows=1 loops=1)
           Output: hotel_slot_inventory.id
           Buffers: shared hit=1 read=453546 written=8
           I/O Timings: read=61967.042 write=0.194
           ->  Index Only Scan using hotel_slot_inventory_id_updated_at_idx on public.hotel_slot_inventory  (cost=0.57..3291347.07 rows=12881 width=4) (actual time=65251.996..65251.997 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Output: hotel_slot_inventory.id
                 Index Cond: ((hotel_slot_inventory.id IS NOT NULL) AND (hotel_slot_inventory.updated_at >= '2021-03-02 13:30:03'::timestamp without time zone) AND (hotel_slot_inventory.updated_at < '2021-03-03 06:15:19.127884'::timestamp without time zone))
                 Heap Fetches: 1
                 Buffers: shared hit=1 read=453546 written=8
                 I/O Timings: read=61967.042 write=0.194
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..256.09 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=304.902..304.903 rows=1 loops=1)
           Output: hotel_slot_inventory_1.id
           Buffers: shared hit=369 read=466
           I/O Timings: read=299.674
           ->  Index Only Scan Backward using hotel_slot_inventory_id_updated_at_idx on public.hotel_slot_inventory hotel_slot_inventory_1  (cost=0.57..3291347.07 rows=12881 width=4) (actual time=304.899..304.899 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Output: hotel_slot_inventory_1.id
                 Index Cond: ((hotel_slot_inventory_1.id IS NOT NULL) AND (hotel_slot_inventory_1.updated_at >= '2021-03-02 13:30:03'::timestamp without time zone) AND (hotel_slot_inventory_1.updated_at < '2021-03-03 06:15:19.127884'::timestamp without time zone))
                 Heap Fetches: 3892
                 Buffers: shared hit=369 read=466
                 I/O Timings: read=299.674
 Planning Time: 0.229 ms
 Execution Time: 65556.982 ms
(28 rows)
```

We can see that this simple index only scan took 65556.982 ms. Majority of time is taken by InitPlan 1 65251.997 ms.. why so?. it just had to fetch the first record from btree index forward and backward search respectively, as query is asking for Min and Max... not needed to fetch all the matching records from btree index
**FYI:** Vacuum didn't helped much.

**Edit Index Bloat Details:**

real_size: 3751411712 = 3.49 GB

extra_size: 470237184 = 448 MB

extra_ratio:12.53

fillfactor: 90

bloat_size: 107053056 = 102 MB

bloat_ratio:2.85

**Table Bloat Size:**
bloat_size: 475283456 = 453 MB

bloat_ratio: 5.088

Comment: Please don't open different questions on the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66452891/postgres-query-plan-why-row-estimation-is-so-wrong

Comment: @S-Man: In both the thread I am asking different question. This has been recommend to me previously, and I found it reasonable.

Comment: You should give us the index definition rather making us guess.

Comment: You did not answer questions requesting more information on the duplicate question... I asked you to check the stats on index bloat, because it's not normal that it has to read 453546 buffers to get one row.

Comment: @bobflux: just did

Answer (score 1):

Your index must be leading with `(id, updated_at...)`.  Note that this index cannot read merely the time range in question, because that is not the first column in the index, and the column that is first is not specified by equality.  So you start scanning the entire index until you find a row that meets the time condition.  I call this an in-index filter. Evidently this took a lot of scanning in the forward direction, and that would be because none of the records at that end of the index meet the time condition. The planner, however, doesn't understand this fact, it thinks it will find the 12881 rows scattered evenly throughout the index. Not all at one end of it.

Unlike a regular (out of index) filter, the plan doesn't report on how many rows were evaluated and then removed by an in-index filter.  That leaves the plans a bit hard to interpret.

There are two pieces of evidence for this interpretation.  One is that the limit nodes exist at all even though you're query doesn't specify a limit.  That can only be in support of the min and max aggregates.  The other is the injection of IS NOT NULL in the index condition when that was not in your query.  I don't know why it does that, but it does indicate an in-index filter (or sometimes a partial index) rather than ordinary index usage.

Comment: Yes my index is on (id, updated_at). I created it this way because earlier I created it like (updated_at,id) but query didn't used that at all and query was very slow running for many minutes, So I reverted the index position and then it eventually used index but that is slow. Not sure how to fix it

Comment: kindly help here.

Comment: The index on `(updated_at,id)` should be fast for this time range, assuming the stats are accurate and there really are only 12881 rows in that time range.  If you have a question about that, you should post it.  (not the unfocused mess you posted last week where you were creating indexes on tables that weren't even the ones you were querying.)