# Postgres explain plan High number of Buffers Shared read, for very slow number of rows

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, explain

**Postgres Version:** 12

**Query:**
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE TRUE, VERBOSE TRUE, COSTS TRUE, BUFFERS TRUE, TIMING TRUE)
SELECT MIN("id"), MAX("id") FROM "public"."hotel_slot_inventory" WHERE ( "updated_at" >= '2021-03-02 13:30:03' AND "updated_at" < '2021-03-03 06:15:19.127884' );

**Query Plan:**

```
 Result  (cost=512.17..512.18 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=65556.920..65556.926 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: $0, $1
   Buffers: shared hit=370 read=454012 written=8
   I/O Timings: read=62266.717 write=0.194
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..256.09 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=65251.998..65252.001 rows=1 loops=1)
           Output: hotel_slot_inventory.id
           Buffers: shared hit=1 read=453546 written=8
           I/O Timings: read=61967.042 write=0.194
           ->  Index Only Scan using hotel_slot_inventory_id_updated_at_idx on public.hotel_slot_inventory  (cost=0.57..3291347.07 rows=12881 width=4) (actual time=65251.996..65251.997 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Output: hotel_slot_inventory.id
                 Index Cond: ((hotel_slot_inventory.id IS NOT NULL) AND (hotel_slot_inventory.updated_at >= '2021-03-02 13:30:03'::timestamp without time zone) AND (hotel_slot_inventory.updated_at < '2021-03-03 06:15:19.127884'::timestamp without time zone))
                 Heap Fetches: 1
                 Buffers: shared hit=1 read=453546 written=8
                 I/O Timings: read=61967.042 write=0.194
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..256.09 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=304.902..304.903 rows=1 loops=1)
           Output: hotel_slot_inventory_1.id
           Buffers: shared hit=369 read=466
           I/O Timings: read=299.674
           ->  Index Only Scan Backward using hotel_slot_inventory_id_updated_at_idx on public.hotel_slot_inventory hotel_slot_inventory_1  (cost=0.57..3291347.07 rows=12881 width=4) (actual time=304.899..304.899 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Output: hotel_slot_inventory_1.id
                 Index Cond: ((hotel_slot_inventory_1.id IS NOT NULL) AND (hotel_slot_inventory_1.updated_at >= '2021-03-02 13:30:03'::timestamp without time zone) AND (hotel_slot_inventory_1.updated_at < '2021-03-03 06:15:19.127884'::timestamp without time zone))
                 Heap Fetches: 3892
                 Buffers: shared hit=369 read=466
                 I/O Timings: read=299.674
 Planning Time: 0.229 ms
 Execution Time: 65556.982 ms
(28 rows)
```

Here in InitPlan1 , just to fetch 12881, it has to read 453546 buffers.. that means there are many buffers which doesn't contain data. Vacuuum also didn't help. Please help here. How can I fix this issue?

**Edit Index Bloat Details:**

real_size: 3751411712 = 3.49 GB

extra_size: 470237184 = 448 MB

extra_ratio:12.53

fillfactor: 90

bloat_size: 107053056 = 102 MB

bloat_ratio:2.85

Comment: What is the index definition? Also you can check the size of the index?

Comment: Please don't open different questions on the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66452891/postgres-query-plan-why-row-estimation-is-so-wrong

Comment: @S-Man: In both the thread I am asking different question. This has been recommend to me previously, and I found it reasonable.

Comment: @bobflux: Index size is 3578 MB. How does that helps?

Comment: Can you show the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements?

Comment: It's a pretty big index! Divide by number of rows in the table, that will tell you how many bytes per row the index uses (please share results). If it looks suspiciously high, suspect bloat. Also check index bloat with this [query](https://github.com/ioguix/pgsql-bloat-estimation/blob/master/btree/btree_bloat-superuser.sql)